# AWS Elastic Beanstalk set root volume through .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The AWS documentation is so large and confusing, I can't seem to get this working.

I have a docker image that I am deploying onto elasticbeanstalk t2 instance. I want to set the volume to 50 gigs.

It creates the Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.1 Platform.

Instance created with:

```
eb create --single --tier webserver --instance_type t2.nano
```

I have tried a few solutions suggested and none of them seem to work when i redeploy or create the instance.

Attempt 1:

Inside `.ebextensions/options.config`

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    RootVolumeType: gp2
    RootVolumeSize: "50"
```

Attempt 2:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            VolumeType:
              'gp2'
            VolumeSize:
              '50'
```

followed by:
`eb deploy`

Neither of these change the size of the volume, it's staying put at default.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any saved configurations? They have higher priority, thus maybe they overwrite your settings in ebextensions.

Comment: I figured it out. My .gitignore was ignoring the config files. The only way I found out is by looking in the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem, my .gitignore was setup to ignore the config files.

Both seem to be valid options, not sure which is better.